# Get connected user information from MySQL database in Android Studio

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-asynctask

I'm building a mobile application in Android Studio for the first time, and in order to connect to MySQL database I used PHP.

I created a login interface (with email and password) which will redirect the user to profile interface where I need to display user's data in text view.

The problem is that I don't know how to get other user's data (for example :name , age ...) in my code, I can only get entered values (email or password).

Could somebody show me how please ?

Login activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=10000;
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT=15000;
    public static final String USER_NAME = "USERNAME";

    EditText _txtemail;
    EditText _txtpassword;

    //CardView _button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        _txtemail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        _txtpassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.matricule);
        
    }

    public void checkLogin(View arg0) {

        // Get text from email and passord field
        final String email = _txtemail.getText().toString();
        final String matricule = _txtpassword.getText().toString();

        // Initialize  AsyncLogin() class with email and password
        new AsyncLogin().execute(email,matricule);
    }

    private class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //this method will be running on UI thread
            pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
            pdLoading.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                // Enter URL address where your php file resides
                url = new URL("http://192.168.1.141/androidfiles/login.inc.php");

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            }
            try {
                // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
                conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                // setDoInput and setDoOutput method depict handling of both send and receive
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                // Append parameters to URL
                Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                        .appendQueryParameter("email", params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter("matricule", params[1]);
                String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

                // Open connection for sending data
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(query);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                conn.connect();

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                // Check if successful connection made
                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    // Read data sent from server
                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                    return(result.toString());

                }else{

                    return("unsuccessful");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            //this method will be running on UI thread

            pdLoading.dismiss();

            if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
            {
                /* Here launching another activity when login successful. If you persist login state
                use sharedPreferences of Android. and logout button to clear sharedPreferences.
                 */

//                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "login successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SuccessActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(USER_NAME, _txtemail.getText().toString());

                startActivity(intent);


                MainActivity.this.finish();

            }else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){

                // If username and password does not match display a error message
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid email or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("exception") || result.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful")) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OOPs! Something went wrong. Connection Problem.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

    }
```

- PHP file

```
<?php

     include 'config.inc.php';
     
     // Check whether username or password is set from android  
     if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['matricule']))
     {
          // Initialize Variable
          $result='';
          $email = $_POST['email'];
          $matricule = $_POST['matricule'];
          
          // Query database for row exist or not
          $sql = 'SELECT * FROM chauffeur WHERE  email = :email AND matricule = :matricule';
          $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
          $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindParam(':matricule', $matricule, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->execute();

          if($stmt->rowCount())
          {
             $result="true";    
          }  
          elseif(!$stmt->rowCount())
          {
                $result="false";
          }
          
          // send result back to android
          echo $result;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Well, you do need to return data other than true or false in your php file as a starting point.

Comment: if i returned it , what will be the change in AsyncLogin ?